# Unable to see tables in the AWS datalake/glue UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, data-lake

[Image showing tables created. (crawler snapshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNEIu.png) 
Unable to see tables under databases tab in the AWS datalake/glue UI even though the Crawler log states that - 2 tables have been created.

2020-09-05T15:16:45.020+05:30   [7bf19dc8-e723-4852-b92f-ccd1ab313849] BENCHMARK : Running Start Crawl for Crawler db1

2020-09-05T15:17:02.149+05:30   [7bf19dc8-e723-4852-b92f-ccd1ab313849] BENCHMARK : Classification complete, writing results to database db1

2020-09-05T15:17:02.150+05:30   [7bf19dc8-e723-4852-b92f-ccd1ab313849] INFO : Crawler configured with SchemaChangePolicy {"UpdateBehavior":"UPDATE_IN_DATABASE","DeleteBehavior":"DEPRECATE_IN_DATABASE"}.

2020-09-05T15:17:23.963+05:30   [7bf19dc8-e723-4852-b92f-ccd1ab313849] INFO : **Created** table customers in database db1

2020-09-05T15:17:23.965+05:30   [7bf19dc8-e723-4852-b92f-ccd1ab313849] INFO : **Created** table sales in database db1

2020-09-05T15:17:24.674+05:30   [7bf19dc8-e723-4852-b92f-ccd1ab313849] BENCHMARK : Finished writing to Catalog

2020-09-05T15:18:30.608+05:30   [7bf19dc8-e723-4852-b92f-ccd1ab313849] BENCHMARK : Crawler has finished running and is in state READY

The role consists of all admin policies. Tried refreshing many times, still cannot see the tables.

Comment: Are you looking for tables under Glue data catalog in the same region that you ran Glue crawler in ? replace region in this link of yours and try https://console.aws.amazon.com/glue/home?region=us-east-1#catalog:tab=tables ? Also what is the source for your crawler and nothing works update the IAM permissions of the Glue service role used in the questionm

Comment: Thanks for your response Prabhakar...

--yes i am looking at the tables in the same region
--I checked, replacing the region name in the link you provided, but still no tables to be seen.
-- Source for crawler is s3 bucket in the same region.
-- for IAM, I have attached all the admin and super policies.

As i shared the log, it is creating 2 tables, only problem is that I am unable to see them under the Data Catalog-> Databases -> Tables

Comment: Can you try creating a new crawler and run on the same dataset? Wanted to see if existing crawler settings might be had to do something. Also check in cloudtrail for create/delete entries refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-cloudtrail.html

Comment: Happens to me to, did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: The account may have lake formation turned on, if so even an iam admin can't see the glue databases. you have to go into lake formation console, administrative roles and tasks, and add your iam account as an admin.